# Akka: how to create a compact json without empty values?

Tags: scala, akka, spray-json

Is it possible with Akka (maybe some Spray "utils"?) to build a compact json feed starting from a `case class` like this:

`case class Stuff (val1: String, val2: String, val3: String)`

built in this way:

`Stuff("one value", "", "another value")`

and get a json in a compact form that will skip the "empty value" and will return:

`{"val1" : "one value", "val3" : "another value"}`

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a simpler one but requires you to construct your `case class` with `Option`.

```
import spray.json._

case class Something(name: String, mid: Option[String], surname: String)

object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val sthFormat = jsonFormat3(Something)
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val sth = Something("john", None, "johnson").toJson
    println(sth) // yields {"name":"john","surname":"johnson"}

  }
}
```

kali's answer with custom writer might be better depending on what you need.

Comment: I would prefer to stick with the `spray.json` solution as I already use it.

Comment: I get: Error:(10, 50) Cannot find JsonWriter or JsonFormat type class for Something
    val sth = Something("john", None, "johnson").toJson

Comment: The fix is: put `MyJsonProtocol` in another file and on top of `println` add ` import MyJsonProtocol._`

Comment: It cannot find the `implicit` for `JsonWriter`. You could do it as you said or just pass the writer directly without relying on the `implicit`. `toJson(MyJsonProtocol.sthFormat)` but it's nasty.

Answer (score 1):

You can define what might happen during the json serialization, if you'll have a few other "stuff" you can define this implicit withing a trait for reuse

```
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization._
import org.json4s.{FieldSerializer, NoTypeHints}
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization

trait EmptySpaceIgnoredJsonable {
    def toJsonWithEmptyThingies : String = {
        implicit val formats = Serialization.formats( NoTypeHints ) +
            FieldSerializer[ this.type ]( doStuffWhileSerializing() )
        write( this )
    }

    def doStuffWhileSerializing() : PartialFunction[ (String, Any), Option[ (String, Any) ] ] = {
        case (x, y : String) if !y.isEmpty => Some( x , y )
        case _ => None
    }
}

// then use it, when ever you require empty "stuff"
case class Stuff (val1: String, val2: String, val3: String) extends EmptySpaceIgnoredJsonable
val stuff = Stuff("one value", "", "another value")
println(stuff.toJsonWithEmptyThingies)
```